# Spring Data JPA: Sorting and paging with joined tables

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario where I want to filter, sort and page over a result where 3 tables take part.

At the moment I use Spring Data JPA's Specification feature to do it on a single entity: `repository.findAll(specification, pageRequest)`.

This works great, but now I have another scenario where the sort / filter attributes are spread over 3 tables which are connected by one-to-many relations.

Here is my scenario:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerEntity ... {
  ...

  @Column(nullable = false)
  public String                                 customerNumber;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  public List<CustomerItemEntity> items;
}


@Entity
public class CustomerItemEntity ... {
  ...

  @Column(nullable = false)
  public String                                 itemNumber;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
  public CustomerEntity customer;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  public List<DocumentEntity> documents;
}


@Entity
public class DocumentEntity ... {
  ...

  @Column(nullable = false)
  public LocalDate                                 validDate;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "itemId")
  public CustomerItemEntity item;
}
```

Is there a way to use `PageRequest` and `Specification` where `customerNumber`, `itemNumber` and `validDate` are used for filtering, sorting and paging at the same time?

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Specification<CustomerEntity> joins = (customer, query, cb) ->  {
    // from CustomerEntity c
    // join c.items i
    Join<CustomerEntity, CustomerItemEntity> items = customer.join("items");

    // join i.documents d
    Join<CustomerItemEntity, DocumentEntity> documents = items.join("documents");

    // // where c.customerNumber = ?1 and i.itemNumber = ?2 and d.validDate = ?3 
    return cb.and( 
            customer.equal(customer.get("customerNumber", customerNumber)),
            items.equal(items.get("itemNumber", itemNumber)), 
            documents.equal(documents.get("validDate", validDate))
    );
};

// sort by c.customerNumber asc
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 2, new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "customerNumber"));

Page<CustomerEntity> customerPage = CustomerRepo.findAll(joins, pageRequest);
```

But I don't know why do you need `Specification` here?

You can make the same more simpler:

```
@Query("select c from CustomerEntity c join c.items i join i.documents d where c.customerNumber = ?1 and i.itemNumber = ?2 and d.validDate = ?3")
Page<CustomerEntity> getCustomers(String customerNumber, String itemNumber, LocaleDate validDate, Pageable pageable);
```

But all this does not make sense since your three entities have sequential one-to-many associations. In this case instead of three conditions you can use only last one: `where d.validDate = ?1`. Then a query method became even easier:

```
@Query("select c from CustomerEntity c join c.items i join i.documents d where d.validDate = ?1")
Page<CustomerEntity> getCustomers(LocaleDate validDate, Pageable pageable);
```

**UPDATE**

To add sorting by a field of joined entity we can use `orderBy` method of the `query`:

```
Specification<CustomerEntity> joins = (customer, query, cb) ->  {

    Join<CustomerEntity, CustomerItemEntity> items = customer.join("items");
    Join<CustomerItemEntity, DocumentEntity> documents = items.join("documents");

    // Ascending order by 'Document.itemNumber'
    query.orderBy(cb.asc(documents.get("itemNumber")));

    return cb.and( 
            customer.equal(customer.get("customerNumber", customerNumber)),
            items.equal(items.get("itemNumber", itemNumber)), 
            documents.equal(documents.get("validDate", validDate))
    );
};

Page<CustomerEntity> customerPage = CustomerRepo.findAll(joins, new PageRequest(0, 2));
```

To sort by several parameters you can pass them to the method separated by commas or by a `List`:

```
query.orderBy(cb.asc(items.get("customerNumber")), cb.desc(documents.get("itemNumber")));
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Btw, I build it with specification because the filters are optional. But I have an additional question: How can I sort by one of the joined columns? I cannot just define those in the PageRequest because then JPA tells me that there is no attribute in `CustomerEntity`. Do you have an idea how to sort by `itemNumber` for example?

Comment: @Tobi I update my answer (don't forget to upvote it if it will help)...

Comment: Thank you, but I have a problem extracting the correct results. When I filter on a certain customer, on a certain item and on documents with certain valid date, I get the correct number of elements in the page object. But when I access the content of the page which are customer entities I get this one customer entity but all its items and documents, although I should only get one item with one document. Do you have an idea how to extract the correct results?

Comment: Working with custom queries I could make the joins in the JQL and let the method return `List<Object[]>` in order to get the joined results. But then I have problem with optional filter parameters. Is it possible to use specifications but changing the return type to `List<Object[]>` where I can continue working on the raw joined data?

Comment: @Tobi I think you should post new question where you will show your current query/result and show your expected result. It's very difficult to understand without seeing them.

Comment: @Tobi according [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) `JpaSpecificationExecutor` methods return only entity matching the given Specification, they cannot return `Object[]`

Comment: I ended up with creating my own Spring data repository using JPA's criteria API in order to return tuples as result. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I do understand the example and it works great but... How can I make it work if the parameter that defines the sort field is coming from Swagger? Basically it works only for fields that are not part of the join or if I specify also the table name (e.g. jointable.field) but, clearly, my users do not know from which table the fields are from...

Comment: Ps I use the SQL Query method with annotation @Query

Answer (score 2):

I found out that you can sort by contents of OneToMany column by using join alias you can create using custom query. In repository my code it was:

```
@Query("select p from Person p join p.roles r")
Page<Person> search(Pageable pageable);
```

So I was able to sort using:

```
r.role
```

Passed from controller using:

```
@PageableDefault(size = 15, sort = "r.role") Pageable pageable
```