# Spring Data JPA: Getting data from joined tables within entity-like object and apply specifications / page requests

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario where I want to filter, sort and page over a result where 3 tables take part. I want to combine each row of the joined result into one entity-like object and apply optional filters on attributes which can come from one of the three root tables.

Here is my scenario:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerEntity ... {
  ...

  @Column(nullable = false)
  public String                                 customerNumber;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  public List<CustomerItemEntity> items;
}


@Entity
public class CustomerItemEntity ... {
  ...

  @Column(nullable = false)
  public String                                 itemNumber;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
  public CustomerEntity customer;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  public List<DocumentEntity> documents;
}


@Entity
public class DocumentEntity ... {
  ...

  @Column(nullable = false)
  public LocalDate                                 validDate;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "itemId")
  public CustomerItemEntity item;
}
```

I want to join all three tables, apply zero up to n filters on arbitrary attributes, filter and have paging on the complete result.
The result should be a flat object containing all joined attributes.

Is there a way to convert joined tables into an object which works like a normal entity?

I would like to have something like this:

- An entity which looks like the joined tables, e.g. `CustomerItemSummaryEntity`.
- Use Spring Data JPA's Specification feature to have filtering, sorting and paging on that `CustomerItemSummaryEntity`. For normal entities I use this: `repository.findAll(specification, pageRequest)`. The reason is that all filters are optional.
- `customerNumber`, `itemNumber` and `validDate` should be used for filtering, sorting and paging (all optional).

Can anybody help here?

Comment: I update my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45743594)...

Comment: Thanks for the hint!
The problem is that when I want to collect the result and map into an object like `CustomerItemSummary` which contains `customerNumber`, `itemNumber` and `validDate` I would go over the page result. But starting from the customer iterating over items iterating the documents I get all results and not only which match the filters.
The page result contains correct information about number of elements, but as said I don't know how to extract only the matching entities from the result.

Comment: I ended up with creating my own Spring data repository using JPA's criteria API in order to return tuples as result. Thanks anyway.