# Pageable + @Query + JOIN (fetch?) in Spring Data don't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to integrate sorting with `Pageable` on joined fields with the use of `@Query` annotation from Spring Data.

1st interface's method (without `@Query` but with the `Pageable`) works like a charm. Same like when I'm fetching only one Employee with the `@Query` but instead of `Pageable` I'm using `Optional<Employee>` there (3rd method). ***But*** the fun begins when I try to put these two all together in one - it won't work anymore.

When I try to sort the data by `name` field it screams with this error:

```java
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: (....).model.employee.Employee
```

So the question is: **how to tell spring to look for `name` in joined fields**? How to do this with Spring Data?

I've already tried several things but they didn't work or I still don't know how to use them properly:

- someone suggested to add `countQuery` to the `@Query` parameters so this corresponds somehow with the pagination ([spring data jpa @query and pageable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345081/spring-data-jpa-query-and-pageable))
- I've followed [Baeldung's tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting) but this doesn't cover joins
- [Spring-Data FETCH JOIN with Paging is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549480/spring-data-fetch-join-with-paging-is-not-working) also suggested using `countQuery` but I'd prefer to stick to `Page<Employee>` rather than `List<Employee>`.

I'll leave some samples of the code below. Feel free to ask for update if I omitted something important.

```java
// Employee
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", schema = "emp")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
    private static final String SEQUENCE = "EMPLOYEE_SEQUENCE";

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = SEQUENCE, name = SEQUENCE, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "employee_number")
    private String employeeNumber;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EmployeeStatus status;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_details")
    private Details details;

    // some other fields ...
}
```

```java
// Details
@Entity
@Table(name = "details", schema = "emp")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Details {
    private static final String SEQUENCE = "DETAILS_SEQUENCE";

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = SEQUENCE, name = SEQUENCE, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    // some other fields ...
}
```

```java
// EmployeeDTO
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class EmployeeDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String employeeNumber;
    private String status;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    // some other fields ...
}
```

```java
// EmployeeRepository
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    // 1st method
    Page<Employee> findByStatus(EmployeeStatus status, Pageable pageable);

    // 2nd method
    @Query(value = "select e from Employee e join e.details where e.status = :status",
            countQuery = "select count(*) from Employee e join e.details where e.status = :status")
    Page<Employee> getEmployeeDetails(@Param("status") EmployeeStatus status, Pageable pageable);

    // 3rd method
    @Query("select e from Employee e join fetch e.details where e.id = :id")
    Optional<Employee> findByIdWithDetails(Long id);

    // ...
}
```

```java
// EmployeeService
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    private final EntityDtoConverter entityDtoConverter;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository, EntityDtoConverter entityDtoConverter) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        this.entityDtoConverter = entityDtoConverter;
    }

    public EmployeeResponse getEmployeesByStatus(EmployeeStatus status, int pageSize, int pageIndex, Sort.Direction sortDirection, String sortColumn) {
        Page<EmployeeDTO> employeePage = employeeRepository.findByStatus(status, PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize, Sort.by(sortDirection, sortColumn)))
                .map(entityDtoConverter::convertEmployeeBaseToDto);
        return new EmployeeResponse(employeePage);
    }

    public EmployeeResponse getEmployeeDetails(EmployeeStatus status, int pageSize, int pageIndex, Sort.Direction sortDirection, String sortColumn) {
        Page<EmployeeDTO> employeePage = employeeRepository.getEmployeeDetails(status, PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize, Sort.by(sortDirection, sortColumn)))
                .map(entityDtoConverter::convertToEmployeeWithDetailsDto);
        return new EmployeeResponse(employeePage);
    }

    // ...
}
```

```java
// EntityDtoConverter
@Component
public class EntityDtoConverter {

    public EmployeeDTO convertEmployeeBaseToDto(Employee entity) {
        return EmployeeDTO.builder()
                .id(entity.getId())
                .employeeNumber(entity.getEmployeeNumber())
                .status(entity.getStatus())
                .build();
    }

    public EmployeeDTO convertToEmployeeWithDetailsDto(Employee entity) {
        return convertEmployeeBaseToDto(entity).toBuilder()
                .name(entity.getDetails().getName())
                .surname(entity.getDetails().getSurname())
                .build();
    }

    // ...
}
```

### EDIT:

This is one of the methods of my rest controller:

```java
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeResponse> getEmployeesByStatus(EmployeeStatus status, int pageSize, int pageIndex, String sortDirection, String sortColumn) {
    try {
        EmployeeResponse employeeResponse = employeeService.getEmployeesByStatus(status, pageSize, pageIndex, Sort.Direction.fromString(sortDirection), sortColumn);
        return employeeResponse.getTotalElements().equals(0L) ? ResponseEntity.noContent().build() : ResponseEntity.ok(employeeResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell specifically for which query you are getting the error ? If it's 2nd Method then I didn't find `name` ?

Comment: yes, it's all about the 2nd one - `getEmployeeDetails`. what do you mean "I didn't find `name`"?

Comment: You want to sort by name of details's property ? Then send sort param like `sort=details.name,asc` using `.`

Comment: the thing is l want it to sort as a user clicks on table column header, I need to give him an option to click on every header he wants so this won't be just name but every field of joined `Details`

Comment: For every field of Details you need to use like  `sort=details.field` that's the way spring data JPA work.

Comment: So if I send this param for details, will I still be able to sort by basic employee fields?

Comment: Yes for employee's field you can send normally `sort=employeeNumber`. Actually you are query in Employee repository then sort will work for Employee entity, `details` is just child entity of that enitity, so you need to use `.` for specifying the property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220198/discussion-between-digitalis-and-user-upvote-dont-say-thanks).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
Specification<Employee> joins = (employee, query, cb) ->  {
            Join<Employee, Detail> details = employee.join("details");

            return cb.and(
                    employee.equal(employee.get("name", name)),
                    details.equal(details.get("name", detailName))
            );
        };

        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 2, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name"));

        Page<Employee> customerPage = employeeRepository.findAll(joins, pageRequest);
```

Here we are trying to inform JPA that this name is foreign key for Employee table.

Comment: i'm not able to write your return contents - idea suggests to use `equals` instead of `equal`, can't use `get` with two params like you, cant use second get

Comment: See this, it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738336/spring-data-jpa-sorting-and-paging-with-joined-tables/45743594#45743594